# Are laser sights visible to enemies in matchmaking?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

I haven't been playing Siege for too long, and I initially put laser sights on all weapons, but I realized I never see any enemies' laser sights. Is this because you can't see enemies' laser sights or just because not many people use them? If they *are* visible to enemies, can you see the dot that hits surfaces or only the laser coming from the gun if you're looking at an enemy?

Answer (score 3):

Yes they are, they can go through windows too.